# Apply class on <ul> based on <li> nth-child selection

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

I have the following list:

```
<ul class="border">
  <li>test1</li>
  <li class="selected">test2</li>
  <li>test3</li>
</ul>
```

Is it possible to use sass for

```
.border {

  &.li:nth-child(3).selected {
      make background color of .border black
  }

}
```

Couldn't figure this out.

Comment: This is not possible yet in the CSS.

Comment: no you can't, you should rely on `JavaScript`.